# Dynamically load data to easyui combobox based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a basic Easyui combobox where i need to add dynamic options based on some condition.
**My Html :**

```
<input id="org_type" name="org_type" class="easyui-combobox" data-options="required: true,valueField:'value',textField:'text',prompt:'Select Org Type'" style="width:100%;" >
```

Now i need to load some options based on some conditions.
for example :

```
if(level == 1){
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
}else{
   <option value="vw">Volvo</option>
   <option value="audi">Saab</option>
}
```

Though that's not the right approach i know. 
I need actually something like this.

Comment: Are you using of basic data, or json?

Comment: I am using basic data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got my own solution. 
Simply i added these JavaScript code when i need to add options dynamically.

```
let options  = [];
if(level == "1"){

options = [
    {
        text: 'Volvo',
        value: 'volvo'
    },
    {
        text: 'Saab',
        value: 'saab'
    }
];

}else if(org_level == "2"){
options = [
    {
        text: 'Marcedes',
        value: 'marcedes'
    },
    {
        text: 'Scania',
        value: 'scania'
    },
    {
        text: 'BMW',
        value: 'bmw'
    }
];
```

}

```
$('#org_type').combobox({
        data: options
})
```

And it work's fine for me. 
Thanks.